# Relation Not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, relationship

I am using Laravel 5.4 and i have 3 tables

```
users
assist
asist_members
```

assist_members table contain

```
id | assist_id | user_id
```

I am trying to get all data using relation
i have added following releation in Assist Model and in thid model i have mentioned table name ,primary key and added following relation

```
public function user(){

       // return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');

        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_id');
    }
```

When i try to retrive i got error

```
  $response=Assist::with('user')->get();
```

if i print $response i am getting error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linking table name is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names. For eg: **User** model and **Assists** models will be linked by **assist_user** table.

but in your case you should override this convention by passing a second argument to the **belongsToMany** method:

```
 public function user(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'assist_members');
 }
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column asist_members.asist_members_id

Comment: The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship and fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'assist_members', 'assist_id', 'user_id');

Comment: @Amirthpall.Thanksi have added key to it .works fine now.thanks for quick answer.any idea about hasmany thorugh for this

Comment: @vision i am more happy than you bro, at least helped one person today. Can you accept my answer so that i can earn some reputation on stackoverflow ? :-)

Comment: @Amirthpal.do you have any idea for this same has many thorugh relation for sam pivot table.thanks

Comment: just define the hasMany relation in model with some other method name that you would like to call where you want to use it. If you would like me to write method tell me the model name you would like to have that relation with.

Comment: same for above tables asist_members is pivot table and contain extra column in it

Comment: in assist table am trying to retrieve all assist members with theire user detail

Comment: Define the users function like below in Assist model:

public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'assist_members', 'assist_id', 'user_id');
    }

Now you should be able to call all users like below:
Assist::users()->all()